# Glassfish Server is not connected

Tags: java-ee, jsf, glassfish, java, primefaces

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь разобраться в Jsf (primefaces), и мало что выходит, а именно собраный war архив в maven-e пытаюсь запустить через Glassfish, сервер запускается, НО в самом начале пишет:

> Artifact qwe-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war: Server
> is not connected. Deploy is not
> available.

А в конце пишет

> Artifact qwe-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:
> Artifact is being deployed, please
> wait...   Artifact is deployed
> successfully.

Вроде как все нормально, после чего открывается моя страница в браузере пустая, хотя в моем index.xhtml [ссылка](http://pastebin.com/64LjPmCX).

По идее, должна быть кнопка с стилями primefaces, которые подключены в pom.xml [ссылка](http://s60.radikal.ru/i167/1410/e9/3facb79d8d04.png) и мой web.xml [ссылка](http://s04.radikal.ru/i177/1410/da/e15976629f8a.png). Может быть, я что-то делаю не так? Я только учусь, поэтому хочу узнать, как и почему не отображается нечего. Вот 3 скрина с настройками гласфиш и результата:
[link](http://s48.radikal.ru/i119/1410/b8/c086f5001deb.png)  
[link2](http://s019.radikal.ru/i643/1410/85/1e149dab613b.png)
[link3](http://i072.radikal.ru/1410/3a/63a1d3ad5751.png)